# Visual Studio 2010 Project Template doesn't show up

Tags: visual-studio-2010, project-template

I tried to edit a project template after exporting it from vs2010 by extracting it and after editing compressing it again.
But after that it won't show up in visual studios new project dialog.

So I tried it again, without the editing. Just extract and compress again. I even used windows zip mechanisms, but still wont work. Only the exported template works fine.

I also tried what's written here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms185298.aspx
to no avail.

So is there some magic incantation nobody told me about to get it to work?

Answer (score 16):

Be carefull following Step 7 in http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms185298.aspx.

**DON'T** send the whole Folder to a zip file... only the files inside!

Comment: +1!!! Thanks so much for this! I spent so much time troubleshooting and the whole reason I kept failing was because I wasn't doing what you said in your last statement.

Answer (score 3):

Actually, there's [a documented way](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms241279%28VS.90%29.aspx) to get VS to populate the template cache folder by just deploying the zipped template to the ProjectTemplates\etc. folder:

```
<Path to devenv.exe> /installvstemplates
```

Works on every version of VS since 2005 (and possibly even earlier versions).

Answer (score 0):

There are actually two places where templates are kept.  *Templates and *TemplatesCache (where * is Item or Project).  You need to update the template in both places.  Note, the cache has the templates extracted from the zip file in a subdirectory that has the same name as the zip.

Comment: where can I find this cache for VS2010? c:\Users\<username>\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\VisualStudio\10.0\ does not contain any templatesCache folder like the others.

Comment: @Sven its under ProgramFiles.  For me, C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\ItemTemplatesCache\